# Cannot Install Cent OS 7

Tags: linux, centos

i'm having extreme difficulty trying to install CentOS 7 on a HP Z640 Workstation,

Specs
http://www8.hp.com/h20195/v2/GetPDF.aspx/c04400040.pdf

I have tried installing CentOS 7 and 6.7 in UEFI and both stall at the same time.

"Waiting for hardware to initialize"

If i install using Legacy the installer goes through all of the steps, and appears to install fine, but once i reboot the SSD has no OS installed on it.

I've tried installing the Minimal and LiveDVD version, bootbale usb and a bootable dvd.

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: Did you have a pre-installed OS on your PC?

Comment: Originally had windows 7 Pro 64-bit

Comment: Turn off the secure boot on your BIOS settings

Comment: Just checked there and Secure boot was already disabled

Comment: Create a  new partition  bios_grub size=1 mib and try to reinstall your OS Legacy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might be suffering from [a problem i ran into in the past on some hp latop](http://technophilefiles.blogspot.co.il/2015/12/installation-of-linux-goes-smoothly-on.html) when I tried installing mint. Try disabling legacy support and then boot into centos and execute grub-install.

Comment: Sorry for the late response but this sort of worked, after disabling it i couldn't boot at all but once i re-enabled it the install worked fined, no idea why it was causing an issue though!